# SQL : Invalid operation: column ""location_update"" does not exist in t1, t2, unnamed_join;

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to multiply two columns `t1.sales * 1/t2.change_time_2` of two tables `table1` and `table2`

table 1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1
(
    sales VARCHAR(100)   ENCODE lzo
    ,location VARCHAR(100)   ENCODE lzo
    ,tax VARCHAR(100)   ENCODE lzo
)
```

table 2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2
(

    change_time_1 DOUBLE PRECISION   ENCODE RAW
    ,change_time_2 DOUBLE PRECISION   ENCODE RAW

)
```

this is what i am trying to do

```
select  t1.sales, "location_update" = 
(CASE 
     WHEN t1.location =  'America' THEN convert(float,t1.sales )
     WHEN t1.location =  'Britain' THEN convert(float,t1.sales ) * 1/t2.change_time_2
     --ELSE 'Over $1000'
  END)
,t1.tax,t2.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on 1=1;
```

I am getting this error

```
Invalid operation: column "location_update" does not exist in t1, t2, unnamed_join;
```

Am i doing the multiplication incorrectly ?

How to fix this ?

Comment: You seem to be using SQL Server syntax for assigning an alias to the `CASE` expression.  This won't work in MySQL.  Also, why are you doing a cross join between the two tables, which seems meaningless?  How are these two tables related to each other?

Comment: You are trying to compare the result of the CASE expression to a non-existing column - obviously that won't work

Comment: the tables dont have anything in common, or any relation, thats why i am trying to use a cross join and multiply one column of t1 with another of t2..without a cross join, how can i do that ?
also if the result of the CASE expression cannot be taken to non-existing column, how do i achieve the mulitplication

Comment: Use an alias `.. t1.sales,  CASE ..  END AS "location_update", ..`

Answer (score 1):

With mysql, you must use an alias :

```
Select  t1.sales,  
(CASE 
     WHEN t1.location =  'America' THEN convert(t1.sales, float )
     WHEN t1.location =  'Britain' THEN convert(t1.sales, float ) * 1/t2.change_time_2

  END) as location_update
,t1.tax,t2.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on 1=1;
```

Be careful : you use [convert](https://sql.sh/fonctions/convert) function not correctly, correct syntax is `CONVERT(expression, type);`